# How to customize jsweet-maven-plugin

Tags: javascript, java

I was generating from java code to JavaScript code using *jSweet Maven* plugin, and also getting successful JavaScript code. Now I want to customise the JavaScript file as per the details mentioned below:

Here I am following some steps like :

1. File new project
2. Maven project
3. Pom.xml file contain some tags which is mention below.

I am using ***NetBeans IDE*** to solve my problem.

**DemoColor.java**

```
package com.company.javatojstest;              
public enum DemoColor   
 {   
    Unknown,   
    Blue,   
    Green,  
    Black,  
    Yellow,  
    White,;  
}
```

And i am getting output file below.

**Democolor.js**

```html
    var com;
       (function (com) {
        var company;
        (function (company) {
            var javatojstest;
            (function (javatojstest) {
                /**
                 *
                 * @author Admin
                 * @enum
                 * @property {com.company.javatojstest.DemoColor} Unknown
                 * @property {com.company.javatojstest.DemoColor} Blue
                 * @property {com.company.javatojstest.DemoColor} Green
                 * @property {com.company.javatojstest.DemoColor} Black
                 * @property {com.company.javatojstest.DemoColor} Yellow
                 * @property {com.company.javatojstest.DemoColor} White
                 * @class
                 */
                var DemoColor;
                (function (DemoColor) {
                    DemoColor[DemoColor["Unknown"] = 0] = "Unknown";
                    DemoColor[DemoColor["Blue"] = 1] = "Blue";
                    DemoColor[DemoColor["Green"] = 2] = "Green";
                    DemoColor[DemoColor["Black"] = 3] = "Black";
                    DemoColor[DemoColor["Yellow"] = 4] = "Yellow";
                    DemoColor[DemoColor["White"] = 5] = "White";
                })(DemoColor = javatojstest.DemoColor || (javatojstest.DemoColor = {}));
            })(javatojstest = company.javatojstest || (company.javatojstest = {}));
        })(company = com.company || (com.company = {}));
    })(com || (com = {}));
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.jsweet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsweet-quickstart</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>javatojs</name>
        <description>A simple project structure to get started with JSweet v2</description>
        <developers>
            <developer>
                <id>rpawlak</id>
                <name>Renaud Pawlak</name>
                <email>renaud.pawlak@gmail.com</email>
            </developer>
        </developers>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
                <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
                <distribution>repo</distribution>
            </license>
        </licenses>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>jsweet-plugins-release</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>http://repository.jsweet.org/artifactory/plugins-release-local</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots />
                <id>jsweet-plugins-snapshots</id>
                <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://repository.jsweet.org/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>jsweet-central</id>
                <name>libs-release</name>
                <url>http://repository.jsweet.org/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots />
                <id>jsweet-snapshots</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://repository.jsweet.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jsweet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsweet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <tsOut>target/ts</tsOut>
                        <outDir>target/js</outDir>
                        <candiesJsOut>webapp</candiesJsOut>
                        <targetVersion>ES3</targetVersion>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-js</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jsweet</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                        only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                <pluginExecutions>
                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>
                                                org.jsweet
                                            </groupId>
                                            <artifactId>
                                                jsweet-maven-plugin
                                            </artifactId>
                                            <versionRange>
                                                [1.0.0,)
                                            </versionRange>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>jsweet</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <ignore></ignore>
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>
                                </pluginExecutions>
                            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsweet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsweet-core</artifactId>
                <version>6-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsweet.candies</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0-20170726</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

> ```
>  In JavaScript file i want to customize from this line,              
>  DemoColor[DemoColor["Unknown"] = 0] = "Unknown"; 
>  to      
>  DemoColor[DemoColor["Unknown"] = Unknown] = "Unknown"; 
>  I.e whenever JavaScript file find unknown then the index value will   
>  automatically change to unknown.
> ```

Thank You.